# How to play video in fully visible cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application i am playing video in UITableViewCell using the following code. it works perfectly.

```
cell2.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:vidURL];
cell2.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[cell2.moviePlayer.view setFrame:cell2.playVW.frame];
cell2.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[cell2.contentView addSubview:cell2.moviePlayer.view];
[cell2.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
```

only those video will play whose cells are completely visible, this is managed by following code. this is also woking

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSIndexPath *indexVisible in tblFeedTable.indexPathsForVisibleRows) {
    CGRect cellRect = [tblFeedTable rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexVisible];
    BOOL isVisible = CGRectContainsRect(tblFeedTable.bounds, cellRect);
    if (isVisible)
    {
        [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexVisible.row]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
}
```

but the problem is when i scroll the table the next cell video play after the complete visible cell. instead of that i want to play only completely visible cells video.

Comment: Does your cell cover the whole screen?

Comment: No, cell not cover whole screen, one cell fully visible and other one is partially visible

Comment: Okay, then you need to define a cell offset where it is fully visible, on scroll delegate check whether the cell reaches that offset on scroll, if reaches, play video for that, and stop all other.

Comment: i have already got complete visible cell but i want to play only current return indexcell video